# Call method on Angular scope from Underscore Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an underscore template that is called from an Angular controller.  I have a dropdown on the template and a call to onchange on the dropdown.  The onchange attempts to calls a method on the scope on the controller.  I have tried everything to get the method called in the onchange but doing this

```
<select onchange="foo(this.value)">
```

gives me

```
foo is not defined
```

and

```
<select onchange="scope.foo(this.value)">
```

gives me

```
scope is not defined
```

and

```
<select onchange="$scope.foo(this.value)">
```

gives me

```
$scope is not defined
```

Is it even possible to call a method on the controller in this way?

Comment: You need to use `ng-change` possibly, since it looks like the method is on scope... and use `ng-model` as well instead of passing around the value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that is calling the _.template() function, assuming its putting the templated value into a variable and has access to scope:

Find the element in the templated markup: var select = $(templatedVar).find('#selectId');

Add a change event: select.change(function() { //call scope function });

Comment: Hi Gareth, I don't see any such line in the templated markup (the html file).

Comment: What line?


You said your angular controller is creating an underscore template, is it not?


If it is, I am assuming the controller is calling _.template(xxx) somewhere in the code?


If it is, then _.template(xxx) returns the templated content for you. Which I'm assuming you're pushing onto the dom somehow.


That templated content is the value you can use jquery selectors on to find the dom element and apply the necessary events to.

Comment: If you must send me code, send it to gw@gdoubleu.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

use ngChange instead attribute of onchange

check this link for more info "https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange"

Comment: I didn't use AngularJS to create the dropdown as I am using Underscore's templating engine which wouldn't allow an Angular dropdown so onchange is the correct choice.